# Unhide worksheet based on cell value in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a workbook that has many tabs, most of which a single person won't use. I want to hide most of these tabs and then unhide the 1 tab the user needs based on a specific cell value in the "Instructions" tab. I've got the following  but it will not work. Any thoughts? I'm a VERY new VBA writer so feel free to talk to me like a 3rd grader.

Tried the following macro but it isn't even being recognized as one:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Set x_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Workbook Setup Instructions")
    Set Rng_1 = x_sheet.Range("C3")


If Rng_1 = "Role 1" Then
Sheets("Role 1").Visible = True

ElseIf Rng_1 = "Role 2" Then
Sheets("Role 2").Visible = True

Else
Sheets("Role 3").Visible = False

End If
```

Comment: What exactly is in `C3`: a formula, a dropdown, or something else? What should happen if the cell is cleared? If a sheet is to be shown (unhidden), should it be activated and should the other two be hidden or remain as they are?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, c As Range
    
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3")) ' `Me` = the worksheet for this code module
    If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'only interested in changes in C3
    
    v = c.Value  'read the new value
    With ThisWorkbook
        'check each sheet
        .Worksheets("Role 1").Visible = (v = "Role 1")
        .Worksheets("Role 2").Visible = (v = "Role 2")
        .Worksheets("Role 3").Visible = (v = "Role 3")
    End With
End Sub
```